# Conditional display of form fields in PloneFormGen

Tags: overriding, ploneformgen

Plone 4.3.3

PloneFormGen 1.7.16

I would like to display or hide a set of fields based on the user's selection from a Selection field. The Fieldset Begin and Fieldset End elements do not answer this, so I am left with an Overrides Enabling Expression for each field. What is the TALES incantation for testing the current value of a form field? Will PloneFormGen dynamically test so that the fields are shown/hidden upon the user changing the selection?

Thank you,

Chuck

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with JavaScript: [1](http://docs.plone.org/working-with-content/managing-content/ploneformgen/javascript.html) and [2](http://ezhaar.blogspot.fi/2012/06/ploneformgen-showhide-fields-based-on.html).

**First** create JavaScript file to the forms folder:

1. Browse to the forms folder through ZMI, or append "/manage_main" to the forms folder URL.
2. Select a File as a new content type to add
3. Define ID and set the content type as "text/plain"
4. Edit the file

Sample js to hide field based on the selection of an another field (modified from [2](http://ezhaar.blogspot.fi/2012/06/ploneformgen-showhide-fields-based-on.html)): (Note: requires selection-list field)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       if($("#selection-fieldname").val() != "I like this") {
           $('#fieldname-to-hide').parent().hide();
       }
       $("#selection-fieldname").change(function() {
           if ($(this).val() == "I like this") {
               $('#fieldname-to-hide').parent().slideDown();
           } else {
               $('#fieldname-to-hide').parent().slideUp();
           }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Second** inject the js to the form's header:

1. Go to the edit of the forms folder.
2. In Overrides tab, type 'here/your-script-ID' to the Header Injection field.

**Third** (optional) make the dynamically hidden field required only when it is visible.

1. Go the field edit and clear the Required check box if checked.
2. In Overrides tab, add a custom field validator:

   python: test(request.form['selection-fieldname'] != 'I like this' or value, False, 'Required when I like this is selected.')